# Is there a method missing in Xamarin's "Google Play Service - Vision" library for face detection?

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, face-detection

I am using Xamarin's "Google Play Services - Vision" library for face detection. How can I adjust the smallest desired face size?

In java there seems to be the method
setMinFaceSize(float proportionalMinFaceSize) in the FaceDetector.Builder class, I can't find this method in the Xamarin library.

Is there a reason why this method is missing or can I adjust this somewhere else?

Comment: Is there a property that sounds like it could be equivalent? For example, I might expect to find a `MinimumFaceSize`, `MinFaceSize`, or `FaceSize` property which would let you set that value. Xamarin often converts simple setters and getters into C# properties. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. No, I can't find a corresponding property. It is the only method missing, all other methods of this class (mostly setters) are perfectly available in Xamarin (as setters too, not properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue after contacting the Xamarin support team.

I was using the current stable version of the library (Xamarin Google Play Services - Vision 27.0.0) and in that release there is indeed no method to adjust the smallest desired face size.

The method is being added in version 29. You can update to version 29.0.0 (currently prerelease) to use it.